# How can I translate a program in WebAssembly Text Format (.wat) to binary format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I want to make a simple WebAssembly interactive fiddle in JavaScript. Given that the user enters the WebAssembly source code in Text Format, how can I convert it to the binary format needed to run it?

I am looking for an in-browser JavaScript-solution.

Comment: Pretty sure browsers don't have compilers written for them and you need a backend for this.

Comment: WebAssembly Text Format is already compiled. I just need it translated to the binary version. The algorithm is not complex, and I was hoping someone knew a JavaScript implementation of it.

Comment: @Aplet123, `new WebAssembly.Module(_)` does the compilation. Only supports Wasm at the moment however, not WAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binaryen - a compiler infrastructure for WebAssembly - has an official JavaScript / WebAssembly port that you can use from JavaScript, including in the browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/binaryen.

Here's how you could use it to parse a WAT, emit a binary and instantiate a module from it:

```js
var binaryen = require("binaryen");

// Create a module from a WebAssembly Text format
var myModule = binaryen.parseText(`(module
 (type $i32_i32_=>_i32 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
 (export "add" (func $add))
 (func $add (; 0 ;) (; has Stack IR ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.add
   (local.get $0)
   (local.get $1)
  )
 )
)`);

// Emit module in a binary format
var wasmData = myModule.emitBinary();

// Use WebAssembly API to instantiate a compiled module
var compiled = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmData);
var instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(compiled, {});

// And use it
console.log(instance.exports.add(41, 1));
```

Note that this particular example uses `require(...)` targeting Node.js, but it should be easy enough to port it to the browser by either using a bundler or including a script on the page pointing to the client-side version of Binaryen from one of the CDNs using [links in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binaryen#usage-with-a-cdn).